# isNan help in an if else statement

Tags: javascript

I am doing an online exercise and I am required to use an if else statement. The isNaN statement is not working. I am required to return a string if the input of number is not an actual number. This won't compile please help:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
    if (number % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (number % 2 !== 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (isNaN(number)) {
        return "you need to enter a number";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Please *please* use correct indentation... also your true case usually should be the last case.

Comment: You need to have `isNan` as first check.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns false because of

```
 else if (number % 2 !== 0)
```

line, So check isNaN before everything like so

```
var isEven = function(number) {
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    return "you need to enter a number";
  } else {
    if (number % 2 === 0){
      return true;
    } else if (number % 2 !== 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
};

console.log(isEven(NaN));
you need to enter a number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `isNan` as first check in you if-else-if condition.

Explanation:

If the argument is not a number, then `number % 2 !== 0` will be true and it will return the value.

Note:
return statement, terminates the execution of the function further and returns the value. So, even if-else-if is not required here.

and beware with Booleans in NaN and empty string.

Example Snippet:

```js
var isEven = function(number) {
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    return "you need to enter a number";
  }
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(isEven(2));
console.log(isEven(3));
console.log(isEven('i am not a number'));
console.log(isEven(true));
```